# Display Transparent View on Top of Default Numeric Keyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, transparent, presentviewcontroller

I want to display a transparent view on top of Keyboard. But even after using bringSubviewToFront method the keyboard appears on top of everything.
Is there a way to do so

I am getting this as the output.

[image: I am Getting this]

This is the Expected output.
Ignore the Keyboard UI, Just want Transparent view on Top.

[image: Expected Output]

I also thought of presenting a View Controller but still got same result.

Comment: present a half controller over it with background color .black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

Comment: The Problem is the table view details above it is dynamic in size

Comment: this is the custom keyboard then you should make your own keyboard

Comment: I will try to present a View Controller which will contain transparent view and bring my tableview on top.

Creating new keyboard and attaching it with OTP View is a very lengthy task as i a almost there

Comment: This also fails
// Show Transparent View
            let transparentViewHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - 130 - (7 * 40)
            transparentView.view.frame = .init(x: 0, y: 130, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: transparentViewHeight)
            //self.view.addSubview(transparentView.view)
            self.present(transparentView,animated: true,completion: nil)

Comment: simple is create your own keyboard 
as i already create it in my app its not much difficult

Comment: Yes thank you so much for your suggestions.
This Approach would work i have already done it.
I am looking if there is any solution for the mentioned problem.